# replace tags in text with images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, replace, gsub

I have a text with ##imageset## tags that I would like replace with the actual imageset images (image_tag).

This is, what my view code looks like:

```
    <% @topictext = topic.text.gsub!(/##imageset##/).with_index { |iset,i| 

        if topic.topic_imagesets.includes(:imageset).order(:position)[i] then
           topic.topic_imagesets.includes(:imageset).order(:position)[i].imageset.imageset_pictures.order(:position).each do |pic|
              '<span>'+image_tag(pic.picture.image.thumb)+'</span>’
           end
        end
     } %>

    <%= @topictext.html_safe if @topictext %>
```

The result is, that the tags are replaced by |pic| which are the records of the ImagesetPictures and not the span with the actual imageset_pictures.picture image_tag:

```
...takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. [#<ImagesetPicture id: 269, imageset_id: 46, picture_id: 280,...>, #<ImagesetPicture id: 268, imageset_id: 46, picture_id: 236,...>] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I came up with:

```
<% @topictext = topic.text.gsub!(/##imageset##/).with_index { |iset,i|

  if topic.topic_imagesets.includes(:imageset).order(:position)[i] then
     topic.topic_imagesets.includes(:imageset).order(:position[i].imageset.imageset_pictures.order(:position).map{ |p|
        '<span>'+image_tag(p.picture.image_en.thumb)+'</span>'}.join("")

  end
} %>

<%= @toptext.html_safe if @toptext %>
```

Probably not the most elegant, but it works fine for me.